# Why I'am getting undefined property when calling a javascript function from another javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'am using OOP javascript method (correct me if I'am wrong pls), to make use of js custom functions across the all website and javascript files.

There is a main `template.js` file were I store the all js functions I need:

```
var template = function(){

    /*** ******************** ***/
    /*** 1.1 MAIN INIT METHOD ***/
    function _init(){
        __initTooltip();
    }

    /*** ********************* ***/
    /*** 1.2 PRIVATE FUNCTIONS ***/

    // some functions before

    function __capitalize(string){
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }

    /*** ************************************************** ***/
    /*** 1.3 MAKE PRIVATE FUNCTIONS ACCESSIBLE FROM OUTSIDE ***/
    return {
        init:function(){
            _init();
        },
        capitalize:function(string){
            __capitalize(string);
        }
    };



}();

$(document).ready(function(){
    template.init();
});
```

so if I need to call a `__capitalize()` function, it will be accessible via the firebug/chrome console like this: `template.capitalize('some Text');`

It should return me `Some text` instead of `undefined` property ... What I'am doing wrong here ? Any one noticed something I missed here pls ?

Comment: You could save yourself the anonymous functions by just returning the private functions: `return {init: _init, capitalize: __capitalize};`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the `capitalize` method.

You need to return the capitalized value from `capitalize`(which was returned by `__capitalize`)

```
    capitalize:function(string){
        return __capitalize(string);
    }
```

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you @Arun, I thought it already returns a value inside the function

Comment: Good eye, I didn't even notice that object literal, but why return an object literal within a class, why not just make it an object literal to begin with ?

Comment: @adeneo - sorry but I don't understand the question about the literal objects

Comment: Thanks, i understand now. I think it would be better to store it inside the private function in sake of good looking code. But your solution is also good point. Maybe I'am going to stick with your way.